# shift folder in url via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

imagine the following situation:

i've got a folder on the webserver:

```
www.domain.com/test/project
```

in "project", i've got my whole php application. in "project" i've also got the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

rewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(util/(css|js))($|/) - [L]

rewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(UI/designs)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which allows me basically to have url like this for example:

```
www.domain.com/test/project/admin/user
```

i've allowed access to "util/(css|js)" for loading the css and js files from ther

but eventually i want to have this url for example:

```
www.domain.com/test/admin/user
```

so basically, to just shift the "project" folder....

is this possible with an .htaccess file?

is this also possible with the following example:

```
www.domain.com/project/admin/user

www.domain.com/admin/user
```

please help me, i often tap into 500 internal server error :(

i tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ http://www.happydomain.org/folder/$1 #[R=301,L]
```

Comment: A 500 internal server error is an invitation to look into the log file of the server. Well, actually not an invitation, rather an order.

Comment: unfortunately i have no access to this log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the solution! =)

this .htaccess must be adden in the "test" folder - concerning my example mentioned in the question

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^project/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/$1 [L]
```